# In which language was Thimbleweed Park game made>

Tags: game-engine, game-development

I am a game developer and I wanted to know in which language was thimbleweed park made? Was it c# or c++ or something else? I searched on google but there is no relevant information about it.

Answer (score 3):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thimbleweed_Park):

> Gilbert had already started to look for adventure game engines in August 2014, but because of his experience of always wanting to modify engines to do exactly what he wants from them, he decided it would be easier to **create his own engine**.
> He already had a **2D graphics engine written in C/C++** that he had used for his non-adventure games The Big Big Castle! and Scurvy Scallywags, which he decided to use for Thimbleweed Park; **[SDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_DirectMedia_Layer) was used** for handling window creation and input, while Gilbert's own code was used for rendering the graphics. The only other thing that was needed for the engine was a scripting language; Gilbert had looked at Lua, and while he considered it "easy to integrate and highly optimized", he disliked its syntax. He considered making his own scripting language, but due to time concerns, he chose the language [Squirrel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squirrel_(programming_language)) instead.